# struts custom validation, compare two field

Tags: validation, struts-1

I'm learning to do struts form validation. I have two fields with email address and I want to check if both of them have same domain address.
For eg. `user1@gmail.com` and `user2@yahoo.com` should throw `error` and `user1@gmail.com` and `user2@gmail.com` should be `success`.

I was going through lot of articles, most of the articles give insights on single field custom validations not on multiple fields.
what is the best approach for above case.
1. Update : is this code valid, and how to add domain check

```
<field property="email1" 
              depends="email"> 
</field> 
<field property="email2" 
         depends="validwhen,email2"> 
     <arg0 name="validwhen" key="form.email1"/> 
     <arg1 name="validwhen" key="form.email2"/> 
     <arg0 name="email" key="email2"/> 
     <var> 
         <var-name>domain_check</var-name> 
             <var-value> (( * this * != null ) 
                      and ( * this * == email1 ))  </var-value> 
     </var> 
</field>
```

Comment: `is this code valid?` No, and I've no idea which kind of language that is. Where have you taken it from ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios  validation rules, in struts form validation using XML ??

Comment: Struts1 maybe ? Because otherwise it should be like this: http://struts.apache.org/docs/form-validation-using-xml.html and this http://struts.apache.org/docs/using-field-validators.html and they're pretty different from your code

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-validator-framework-example/  Can you suggest some pointers to look at

Comment: Yes, that is Struts1. Take a look at this to start: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/struts2-form-validation-basic-example-using-xml

Answer (score 0):

In your Struts form class (that extends `ActionForm`), override the `validate` method and validate both your `email1` and `email2` field. If the fields match return a `null` or return an `ActionErrors` (See this [example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-custom-validation-example-1.html)).

Struts 1.x XML validation configuration are designed for field validation. I have not seen it used for cross validation (as yet).